# I have a problem in deploying my app on render.com

Tags: node.js, deployment, redis

On my project, I used Kuejs to delay job functionality.Although it works well on my local system, it is displaying this error while deploying.Despite reinstalling the radius,restarting the redis, I am still encountering the same error.
[Error while Deploying on render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlSHY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.